# Evitar recarga o redirección de url con Node.js - express

Tags: nodejs, express

Soy nuevo en esta tecnología, estoy intentando subir una imagen a mi directorio de la página web que estoy realizando, lo he logrado pero no con el efecto deseado.

Al subir la imagen yo quiero que mi página quede estática. En este ejemplo al subir la imagen con éxito la línea

```
return res.end('Uploaded successfuly');
```

me redirige a la url

```
http://127.0.0.1:8081/file_upload
```

y es eso lo que no quiero, he comentado esa linea porque quiero permanecer en la url

```
http://127.0.0.1:8081/index.html
```

pero la página queda como recargando y supongo que es porque no le he indicado que la carga ha finalizado con éxito con

```
return res.end('Uploaded successfuly');
```

hay forma de evitar redireccionamientos o recargas en express?

CLIENTE

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>File Upload</title>
 </head>

<body>
  <h3>File Upload:</h3>
  Select a file to upload: <br />

  <form action = "http://127.0.0.1:8081/file_upload" method = "POST" 
     enctype = "multipart/form-data">
     <input type="file" name="foo" size="50" />
     <br />
     <input type = "submit" value = "Upload File" />
  </form>

 </body>
</html>
```

SERVIDOR

```
 var express = require('express');
 var app = express();
 var path = require("path");
 var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
 var multer  = require('multer');
 app.use(express.static('public'));
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

 app.get('/index.html', function (req, res) {
 res.sendFile( __dirname + "/" + "index.html" );
 })


var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, '../public/upload/temp')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, "llelele.jpg")
  }
})

var upload = multer({ storage: storage })



 app.post('/file_upload', upload.single('foo'), function(req, res) {
  if (req.file) {
  console.dir(req.file);

 // return res.end('Uploaded successfuly');
 }
 //res.end('No file found');
 });

 var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
   var host = server.address().address
   var port = server.address().port

   console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
 })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu formulario tiene definido

```
action = "http://127.0.0.1:8081/file_upload"
```

Y ahí es donde te va a llevar.

Una solución rápida sería que, terminando el upload exitoso, lo redirigieras a index.html

```
res.redirect('/index.html');
```

Pero dijiste que no querías redirecciones. Así que la opción más correcta, **usando jQuery y su método ajax**, es usar un elemento [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData). En tu caso yo le pondría un ID al formulario dejándolo como:

```
<form id="uploader" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="foo" size="50" />
  <br />
  <input type = "submit" value = "Upload File" />
</form>
```

Para después declarar:

```
jQuery('#uploader').on('submit',function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();   
    var form = $('#uploader')[0];
    var formData = new FormData(form);

    jQuery.ajax({
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8081/file_upload',
      data: formData,
      type: 'POST',
      contentType: false,
      processData: false
    }).then(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    });
});
```

Y en este caso, no olvides retornar una respuesta desde el backend para que la petición ajax reciba un header 200 y entienda que todo funcionó.

PD: Esto también se puede hacer sin jQuery pero es mucho más engorroso.

Comment: Usando JavaScript puro y sencillo también [se hace en pocas líneas](http://pastebin.com/gSmRZm28).

Comment: con XMLHttpRequest como en los años 90?

Comment: Entonces toma [fetch](http://pastebin.com/jJ3wbDPq).

Comment: Y el soporte IE11?

Comment: Entonces toma [babel](https://babeljs.io) o [un polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch) xD.

Comment: jQuery no es más que un gran polyfill para IE6

Comment: No lo discuto, y por esa y más razones, jQuery ya debe dejar de existir (sarcasmo) xD. Fuera de bromas, buena respuesta, pero deberías dar una alternativa en JavaScript en su escencia más pura (no todos usan jQuery solo para AJAX). +1.

Comment: jQuery, google y StackOverflow constituyen todo mi conocimiento :(

Comment: Sobre todo el último ;)